# Are linux IO ports software abstractions or real hardware ports

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, linux-device-driver

I am learning linux device drivers.
I learned about ports. I am confused that are ports in linux a software abstraction or are real hardware ports.

In the below device driver I wrote a code to allocate a port and to write or read.

The port is allocated even if there is no new hardware connected. What can be the reason?

Another problem is that when I write into the port using oub() and when I read from port using inb() then I always get the value 255 irrespective of what I wrote into the port.

```
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/ioport.h>

struct resource *p;

static int start(void)
{
    printk("module registered\n");
    p=request_region(0x0062, 1, "my_port");
    if(p==NULL)
    {
            printk(KERN_ALERT "port allocation failed\n");
            return 0;
    }
    outb(12, 0x0062);
    return 0;
}

static void stop(void)    
{
    printk("module unregistered\n");
    unsigned a;
    a=inb(0x0062);
    printk("%d\n", a);
    release_region(0x0062, 1);
}

module_init(start);
module_exit(stop);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

I allocate the port and write into it while inserting the module and read from it while unregistering the module.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: They're actually x86 I/O ports, not Linux I/O ports.

Comment: Ports don't have to be readable *and* writeable.  A port could be read-only or write-only. *"The port is allocated even if there is no new hardware connected"* -- You didn't "allocate" a port; all you did was call **request_region()** which is a bookkeeping routine to keep track of which drivers are using which port addresses.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, in the course of the years, CPU manufacturers did not agree on a single mechanism for accessing devices' registers. There are therefore two modes, and a single hardware architecture can implement one mode or the other. These two modes are

- Port-mapped I/O (PMIO):

  - Separate address space for memory and I/O
  - Implemented by a few CPU manufacturers (x86 included)
  - Concept of I/O ports
- Memory-mapped I/O (MMIO):

  - Same address space for memory and I/O
  - Most CPU manufacturers (e.g., ARM)
  - The difference between registers and memory is transparent to software
  - Concept of I/O memory

The book Linux Device Drivers 3rd edition ([freely available on-line](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)) illustrates this difference and how to access each kind of I/O from a kernel driver.